# Regex of changing numbers

Tags: regex

I would use regex to select one changing number
For example in the following example I would select 12090343 that I could change

I use:

```
preg_match (/(?<=Dossier.N..)(.*)(?=-)/)
```

It works but it's not so clean I think  because the number of spaces could change and so it will not detect the number any more

```
                                        Dossier N° 11110144-001          Pvt du : 03/09/2013 à 7:16
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Have you tried my solution or your problem has been solved ?

Comment: Sorry Sniffer I didn't see it before 
It works like a charm 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following expression:

```
/Dossier[^0-9]*\K([0-9]*)(?=-)/
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bQ5sJ9)

Comment: Hello Sniffer :)
Thank you a lot
Worked like a charm for me ;)
Best regards
Amorino

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, but you could *slightly* clean it up by .*not* grouping the number and making it match digits:

```
(?<=Dossier.{0,3}N.{0,3})\d+(?=-)
```

Most regex engines can't handle look behinds of arbitrary length, so rather than using the simpler (but unbounded) expression `\s*`, you must use a limited length expression like `\s{0,3}` to allow "some" whitespace.

Comment: Thank you very much
Is there a way to skip all spaces instead of .. (for tow spaces) that could change?
Best regards
Amorino

Comment: Where can the spaces be?

Comment: Hello Bohemian,
The spaces can be between Dossier and N and between N and the number
In this case I made .. after N for example but it could change to 3 spaces and so it will not detect the number any more
Thank you ;)

Comment: See edited answer for optional whitespace in a look behind

Comment: Hello Bohemian thank you,
For Dossier N° 12090343-034 (?<=Dossier\s{0,3}N\s{0,3})\d+(?=-) gave nothing I tested it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
Best regards
Amorino

Comment: Hello Bohemian,
Tried it but always nothing 
Best regards
Amorino

Comment: I notice in your question you used `&nbsp;` in your input. Does your input *literally* have those characters, or was that a formatting attempt by you? If they are literally there, change `{0,3}` to `{0,30}` or similarly larger number and try that.

Comment: It was a formatting attempt by me :)

Comment: Please post the exact input you have so i can make it work. I am just guessing otherwise. Edit your question and post the input as "code" so we can see whitespace etc as-is

Comment: Thank you 
Done ;)
Sorry I'm new here and this is my 1st post :)
Please see here : http://regexr.com?368j5
Best regards
Amorino